# How do I turn cheats on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing a modded Minecraft world by myself, and I would like to teleport between waypoints. I didn't know you needed cheats on to do it. How do I turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not create the world with cheats, there is a handy little trick to get them. Go into the escape menu, then click `Open to LAN`. Enable cheats there and click Start. You can now use cheats in that world until you close it, then you will need to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Take your world's level.dat file and upload it to the nbt editor here.

https://irath96.github.io/webNBT/

Change the "allowCommands" field to 1.

Then save and overwrite your world's level.dat file with the modified one.

Note: Make sure to make a world backup when doing unsupported data modifications to the world.